# Unable to create outlet using trackpad

Tags: macos, xcode, trackpad

I am using Xcode 7 on a MacBook Air without mouse. Just the trackpad for navigation.

I don't know how to create an outlet to a label using trackpad.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution :

1. we need to 'create' right click on trackpad first. This is done by Preferences>Trackpad> Point&Click> Secondary click> click in bottom right corner
2. once step one is done, go to xcode. hover the mouse over the view for which you wish to create an action or outlet, do not tap, press right click on the trackpad with one hand and drag the view with other hand (without tapping).

That's all is required.

Answer (score 1):

Hold <kbd>⌃ ctrl</kbd> and drag as usual.

Comment: I am left handed and this MacBook Air